# How to find out what is sending "agent.remove" to my moveTo block?

Tags: anylogic

I have a `moveTo` and `delay` block between a `restrictedAreaStart` and a `restrictedAreaEnd`. While running my simulation, the agent inside the `moveTo` block occasionally gets removed. I know it's removed, because I added a `traceln` command to the **On remove:** field of the `moveTo` and it triggers.

[image]

This `remove` causes the restrictedArea to never drop below capacity, so the model effectively stops. I don't want this to occur, but I don't know why it's occurring. I've eliminated an issue with the schedule and END_OF_SHIFT. How do I find out where the `remove` command is coming from (e.g. what block, line of code, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for 'moveThruAL.remove' and for any instances where these agents are destroyed ('remove_myAgentPopulation')

Comment: So unfortunately, only 1 instance of `.remove` occurs in the entire program and it doesn't relate to this block. I believe the agent is being removed because of another `seize` task or an `endOfShift` which is fine, but it still causes the issue. As a work around, can I manually call a method to decrease the `restrictedArea.entitiesInside()`?

Comment: nope, not possible. Then, you need to work backwards eliminating possible causes...

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I'm looking at preemptions and priorities. Seeing if that does the trick.  I wish the documentation explained them a bit better.